Tikz: intersection of a named path and a line in the direction of the path
In the MWE below, the idea is to find the intersection point of the vertical line passing from 2,0 and the named path mycurve. First, I had to establish a path that I know is long enough to intersect with the curve. Is there a way to to remove that restriction, that path shall not need to intersect but its direction is on the way to intersection. Maybe something similar to the commented out line?
\documentclass[border=1pc,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (6,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,6);
\coordinate (D) at (2,0);

\draw[->] (O)--(C);
\draw[->] (O)--(B);
\draw [very thick, name path=mycurve] (0,0) .. controls (4,1) and (2,5) .. (6,6);
\path[name path=path1] (D)--(2,10);
\path [name intersections={of=mycurve and path1, by={E}}];
% \path [name intersections={of=mycurve and ($(D)+(0,1)$), by={E}}];
\draw (2,0)--(E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You could replace \path[name path=path1] (D)--(2,10); with \path[name path=path1] (D)--(D|-current bounding box.north); to guarantee your point is high enough (and not unnecessarily high).

In Metapost you could find the right place with the solve macro.  I am not sure whether such a facility is available in tikz. The macro is inherited from plain Metafont, and is explained in chapter 20 of The Metafont Book. Here is my approach, using solve:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  path xx, yy, ff;
  xx = origin -- 200 right;
  yy = xx rotated 90;
  ff = origin {4,1} .. {4,1}(7cm,7cm);

  numeric a, b; a = 2cm;
  vardef f(expr t) = (a > xpart point t of ff) enddef;
  b = solve f(0,length ff);

  draw point b of ff -- (a,0) withcolor red; 

  drawarrow xx;
  drawarrow yy;
  cutdraw ff withpen pencircle scaled 1;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Compile this with lualatex to get a PDF that looks like this:

Notes
If you knew the equation of the curve, then you would not need this brute-force approach.  For a given value of x you would simply draw (x,0)--(x,f(x)).   In the OP case the curve appears to be the logistic function suitably scaled.
And of course, you can always use the intersection... macros, so (in this case) you can find b with
(b, whatever) = ff intersectiontimes yy shifted (a,0);

or, more generally,
path s; s = llcorner ff -- ulcorner ff;
(b, whatever) = ff intersectiontimes s shifted (a,0);

or, most generally,
(b, whatever) = ff intersectiontimes (up--down) scaled infinity shifted (a,0);

Details
(from the MFBook, p.176)
To use solve in MP, you first define a macro f such that f(x) is either true or false; then you say
solve f(true_x, false_x)

where true_x and false_x are values such that f(true_x) = true and f(false_x) = false.  The resulting value of x will be at the cutting edge between truth and falsity, in the sense that x will be within a given tolerance of values for which f yields both outcomes.
vardef solve@#(expr true_x,false_x)= 
tx_:=true_x; fx_:=false_x;
forever: x_:=.5[tx_,fx_]; exitif abs(tx_-fx_)<=tolerance;
if @#(x_): tx_ else: fx_ fi :=x_; endfor
x_ enddef; 

Notice how f is passed as a suffix.  The internal value tolerance is set to 0.01 in plain.mp

In your case, where you define coordinates of axis, one way to limit your vertical line can be the following:
\path [name path=b] (D) -- (D |- C);

(I change paths name for shorter writing). So, the complete MWE can be:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (B) at (6,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,6);
\coordinate (D) at (2,0);

\draw[<->] (C) |- (B);
\draw [very thick, name path=a] (0,0) .. controls (4,1) and (2,5) .. (6,6);
\path [name path=b] (D) -- (D |- C);  % <---
\draw [name intersections={of=a and b, by=E},blue]  (D) -- (E);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I wasn't aware of that \draw[<->] (C) |- (B); trick. Thanks!

Do I understand correctly? That, this method would not work if I, say, wanted to draw a line from, say, (2,0) to the curve with an angle, and find the intersection point?

@blackened, I provided solution which solve problem asked in your question. Proposed solution is not general but for this particular case. If you have new problem, please ask new question. So far I can't gueass what you now after.
